# hard drive was plugged into a wireless router and now doesn't work

Tags: external-hdd

This is the output of `fdisk -l`:

[image]

I can't get it to mount or anything.

Comment: Before doing that, did it already have two large partitions, one zero-byte partition and one small?

Comment: what OS was the router running? How did you disconnect the drive from the router?

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer, to be updated. As such, I made it CW to encourage anyone to update it.

There's a chance that the disk only has the partition table overwritten. I would start with gpart.

Install it with `sudo apt install gpart`.

Run `gpart -W /tmp/guessed_table -l /tmp/guess_log /dev/sdb` and edit your question with the output of `gpart` and the file `/tmp/guess_log`.

This command will take a while, since it reads the disk.

If the result looks sane, you can either manually create the partitions suggested, or rerun `gpart -W /dev/sdb /dev/sdb` to write the result to disk.